# How can I submit an application online for extension of work permit in Canada?

Tags: canada, online-resources

My work permit has expired on December 31, 2023.

I need to submit an online application. I am not finding the page I need to create an account.

How can I submit an application online for extension of work permit in Canada?

After logging into the following page, I don't see any link for creating a new application:

- https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account.html

[image]

Comment: You **can't** work [in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/extend.html) now that your permit expired > To maintain your status, we must receive your application before your work permit expires. We determine the date and time an application is received 2 ways. Contact a immigration lawyer to get what the next steps are